# routingProvide not found AngularJs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-routing

I am just trying to learn Angular.Js and got stuck here watching a tutorial.
I just created a demo App with the following code ... and I am getting an the following error. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
   Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module demoApp due to:        [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $routeProvider



   <!doctype html>
<html lang="en" data-ng-app="demoApp">
<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>My HTML File</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">


</head>
<body>

<!-- Placeholder for views -->

  <div>
    <div data-ng-view=""> </div>
  </div>

<script src="lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular/angular-route.js"></script>

<script>

  var demoApp = angular.module('demoApp',[]);

  demoApp.config(function ($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
    .when('/',
      {
        controller: 'SimpleController', 
        templateUrl: 'partials/view1.html'
      })
    .when('/view2',
      {
        controller: 'SimpleController',
        templateUrl: 'partials/view2.html' 
      })
    .otherwise({
      redirectTo: '/'
    })
  });



  function SimpleController($scope)
  {
    $scope.customers=[
      {name:'AB',city:'Glasgow', cash:20},
      {name:'CD',city:'United States', cash:30},
      {name:'EF',city:'India', cash:40}
    ];

    $scope.addCustomer = function (){
      $scope.customers.push({
        name: $scope.newCustomer.name,
        city: $scope.newCustomer.city,
        cash: $scope.newCustomer.cash
      });
    };

  }


  demoApp.controller('SimpleController', SimpleController);

</script>

</body>

</html>
```

view1.html

```
<div class="container">

    <h2>View1</h2>
    </br>
    Name: 
    <br/>
    <input type="text" data-ng-model="filter.name" />
    </br>
    <ul>
        <li data-ng-repeat="cust in customers | filter:filter.name"> {{ cust.name }} - {{ cust.city }} - {{ cust.cash | currency:{£} }} </li>
    </ul>

    </br>
    Customer name: </br>
    <input type="text" dta-ng-model="newCustomer.name" />
    </br>

    City: </br>
    <input type="text" data-ng-model="newCustomer.city" /> 
    </br>

    Cash: </br>
    <input type="text" data-ng-model="newCustomer.cash" />
    </br>

    <button type="button" data-ng-click="addCustomer()" value="Add Customer" />
    <a href="#/view2">View 2</a>
</div>
```

Comment: if using external non core modules need to add them as dependency in the empty array you have when you create your main module. I see you have `routing-js` being loaded...if that is external module need to inject it as dependency

Comment: @charlietfl great ... that solved the problem

Comment: Yeah, they separated the routing bits from core somewhere between 1.0.8 and 1.2. Switching to 1.0.8 would also have solved the problem but I think staying on the 1.2 branch is a good idea since it seems to be close to a release now.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the fix @charlietfi. The syntax to inject Routing into your demoApp in Angular version 1.2 and above is:

```
<script>

var demoApp = angular.module('demoApp',['ngRoute']);

...
```

Answer (score 0):

Add ngRoute dependancy in the module.

```
var demoApp = angular.module('demoApp',['ngRoute']);
```

Also include angular-route.js

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="angular-route.js"></script>
```